# C++ Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c++, visual-c++, object

When I try to compile the following program it says "Build failed. Object reference not set to an instance of an object" . I'm kinda new to c++ so if anybody can help me it'll be great . I'm just trying out some example I saw in a book so I don't know whats wrong with this .

```
using namespace std;

class matrix
{
    int m[3][3];

    public:
        void read(void);
        void display(void);

        friend matrix trans(matrix);
}

void matrix :: read(void)
{
    cout<<"Enter the elements of the 3x3 array matrix : \n";
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            cout<<"m["<<i<<"]["<<j<<"] =";
            cin>>m[i][j];
        }
    }
}

void matrix :: display(void)
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        cout<<"\n";
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            cout<<m[i][j]<<"\t";
        }
    }
}

matrix trans(matrix m1)
{
    matrix m2;
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            m2.m[i][j] = m1.m[j][i];
        }
    }
    return(m2);             //returning an object
}

int main()
{
    matrix mat1,mat2;
    mat1.read();
    cout<<"\nYou entered the following matrix :";
    mat1.display();

    mat2 = trans(mat1);
    cout<<"\nTransposed matrix :";
    mat2.display();

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tell us the source code line, that the compiler complains about.

Comment: @millimoose you can't find compiler errors with a debugger :-)

Comment: If I add `#include <iostream>` `#include <curses.h>` a semicolon after the class declaration and compile with `-lncurses`, this compiles and runs without errors.

Comment: @TorstenRobitzki Derp. I was thrown by the message that indicates a NPE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - Insert semi-colon after the class definition
2 - Insert the correct headers

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <conio.h>
```

3 - Try getting a compiler that is a bit more descriptive with regards to errors. I did all that i mentioned and your program ran. Try it

Comment: Thank you very much for all the answers. Yeah I missed the semicolon after the class declaration. But I don't understand as you said this code works fine in visual studio but since I was using ubuntu earlier I used the IDE MonoDevelop to compile the program . And still after fixing those bugs it gives the same error in monoDevelop but works fine in visual studio. Anybody has any idea why this is happening ?

And Btw if you can recommend a good IDE to use inside ubuntu to write c++ code that'll be really helpful. 

Thank ya'll very much.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers. I just figured out that using the terminal itself to write and compile the code is way easier than using an IDE inside ubuntu. And the bugs can be identified easily in that since they provide better description about the errors. 
Thanks again for the help.

Comment: No prob.I would think the being something centered around how Visual Studio is built. It is one of the most coder friendly IDE's so that make explain a bit of it. Top of the List for me is VS but i've used Netbeans and it works good too and you could maybe "C Free"

Answer (score 0):

It compiles fine after you fix your missing semi-colon (after your class declaration) and add either `#include <conio.h>` (Visual Studio) or `#include <curses.h>` (for a POSIX system) for the `getch()` function (which is not a standard function).